# Properties always return zero / null values

Tags: c#, .net

We have been given an assignment to develop a Shopping cart using C#
Which has Item (Properties: name, price)
ItemOrder(Properties: Item,Quantity)
I am trying to find out the net price of a product as price*quantity, but the price property always returns 0, I even tried printing the name and it appears a null
The quantity appears properly though.

Class Item

```
private string name; 
private double price;

public string Name { get { return name; } set { name=value;} }
public double Price { get { return price; } set { price = value; } }
public Item()
{
    Name = this.name;
    Price = this.price;
}
public Item(string name, double price)
{
    Name = name;
    Price = price;
}
```

Class ItemOrder : Item

```
private Item product;
private int quantity {get; set;}

public int Quantity { get {return quantity ;} set { quantity=value ;} }

public ItemOrder()
{
    this.product.Name = Name;
    this.product.Price = Price;
    this.Quantity = Quantity;

}
public ItemOrder(Item product, int quantity)
{
    this.product=product;
    Quantity = quantity;
}
```

Main Method:
The ItemOrders are properly added within the cart, and printed, But i am unable to access the price and name for calculations

```
List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
Item pancakes = new Item("Pancakes", 6.25);
inventory.Add(pancakes);
List<ItemOrder> currentCart = new List<ItemOrder>();
ItemOrder item = new ItemOrder(inventory[userInput], quantity);
currentCart.Add(item);
foreach (ItemOrder i in currentCart)
{
    double currentPrice = 0; 
    currentPrice = (i.Price*.i.Quantity);
    Console.WriteLine("(" + (currentCart.IndexOf(i) + 1) + ") : " + i.ToString() + "\t        "+currentPrice);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You `ItemOrder()` constructor look very strange - please explain what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: what's the value of `userInput`? You also might want to change your variable names as to not cause confusion (`this.product=product;`)

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov. your `ItemOrder()` looks really odd.

Comment: Your ItemOrder constructor sets this.Price = Price but where does Price come from? You probably want to change it to public ItemOrder(double Price, String Name)

Comment: ItemOrder() is a non parametric constructor
userInput is the input i am taking to add items in the cart.
the items adding in cart and print logic is working perfectly fine, its the price i am worried about..
This is the output i am getting 
    Your Cart Contains:
    No. | Product           Price           Quantity                Price
    (1) : Onions            4.25            5               0

Comment: I don't even see where `ItemOrder.Price` is declared, but you're trying to use it in your Main Method. `Item` has a `Price` and `ItemOrder` has a `Item`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
ItemOrder item = new ItemOrder(inventory[userInput], quantity);
```

You are calling this constructor:

```
public ItemOrder(Item product, int quantity)
{
    this.product = product;
    Quantity = quantity;
}
```

so the price that you're looking for is actually inside the `product` variable.

Try to add `Product` as a public property:

```
public Item Product { get {return product;} set { product=value ;} }
```

and replace this line:

```
currentPrice = (i.Price*.i.Quantity);
```

with this:

```
currentPrice = (i.Product.Price * i.Quantity);
```

Comment: Thanks @ekad I changed the property to public and changed the non parametric constructors! worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems here.

1. First, if your getters and setters are *that* simple, there's no reason not to use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). You can rid of the backing properties and use `{ get; set; }` instead.
2. There's no need to initialize the properties to *themselves* inside the default constructor.
3. `(i.Price*.i.Quantity)` isn't right. You need to access the `Price` of the `product` inside the `ItemOrder` somehow, and `*.` should be just `*`
4. The easiest way to expose the `product` that's referenced by an `ItemOrder` is to make a public property.
5. You probably want to print the `Name` of the item, and not simply call `ToString()` (which will return `Item`).

For example:

```
public class Item {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public Item()
    {
    }
    public Item(string name, double price)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
public class ItemOrder
{
    public Item Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public ItemOrder()
    {
    }
    public ItemOrder(Item product, int quantity)
    {
        this.Product = product;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    Item pancakes = new Item("Pancakes", 6.25);
    inventory.Add(pancakes);
    List<ItemOrder> currentCart = new List<ItemOrder>();
    ItemOrder item = new ItemOrder(inventory[0], 2); // stand in values for userInput and quantity
    currentCart.Add(item);
    foreach (ItemOrder i in currentCart)
        {
            double currentPrice = i.Product.Price*i.Quantity;
            Console.WriteLine("(" + (currentCart.IndexOf(i) + 1) + ") : " + i.Product.Name + "\t        " + currentPrice);
        }
}
```

This will print

```
(1) : Pancakes          12.5
```

Comment: I changed the non parametric constructors! Thanks!
and declared Item product as public instead of private
but still I wonder will i be able to accomplish it by setting the property as private?